# How to make delete button delete a user in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I am new to AngularJS, and I need some help of trying to make the delete button, to delete a user in AngularJS. If anyone can help, I will be thankful. Thanks in advance.

> Here is my delete button I have created

```
<button type="button" 
         class="delete" 
          ng-click="" 
          ng-show="!inactive">Delete</button> 
    //The user view 
   <div class="people-view">
  <h2 class="name">{{people.first}}</h2>
    <h2 class="name">{{people.last}}</h2>

  <span class="title">{{people.title}}</span>

  <span class="date">{{people.date}} </span>



</div> 



//Controller
 app.controller('MainController',['$scope', 'people', '$routeParams',
function($scope, people, $routeParams) {
people.success(function(data) {
 $scope.people = data[$routeParams.id];


   });
  }]);
```

Comment: where is a logic or details about your Users. please post

Comment: see updated question please

Comment: Are you use ng-repeat to display user ? And what language in server side you use ?

Comment: I am not using any ng-repeat. I am grabbing the users from my json file.

Comment: please provide code you display it . And what language in server side you use ?

Comment: @MaximShoustin Does that kind of help ?

Comment: Just copy and paste your controller code here that will be helpful for us to answer.

Comment: i have updated the question with my controller.

Answer (score 2):

So in `ng-click` call a function named `deleteUser` and pass the id you are getting for that user.

```
//HTML
<button type="button" 
         class="delete" 
          ng-click="deletePeople(id)" 
          ng-show="!inactive">Delete</button> 
//The user view 
<div class="people-view">
  <h2 class="name">{{people.first}}</h2>
  <h2 class="name">{{people.last}}</h2>
  <span class="title">{{people.title}}</span>
  <span class="date">{{people.date}} </span> 
</div>
```

So now inside you controller make a function to delete the user. If you are using it inside the `ng-repeat` then you should pass parameters accordingly. According to your code, you may pass it.

```
 //Controller
 $scope.deletePeople = function (id){
  //here comes your delete code.
  //pass id from the ng-click function.
  //based on that id find the record in the $scope.people array and remove that from the array.
  //you can use javascript splice function to remove it.

  var userToDelete;
  $scope.people.forEach(function(p, index){
    if(p.id == id){
       userToDelete = index;
    }
  });

  $scope.people.splice(userToDelete, 1);
 }
```

Here is a plunker example.
https://plnkr.co/edit/GbKHSER1r992D5ImXJ7n?p=preview

Comment: so for my deletePeople function(id), can I do something like this:              var index = $scope.people.indexOf(people);

    $scope.people.splice($index, 1);

Comment: Yaa sure, If you are using ng-repeat then you can pass index in ng-click function and based on that index you can remove a particular person or this way also you can do the same.

Comment: what if I am not using ng-repeat. Can you show me the function you have implement it?

Comment: Your people contains which things can you mention here?

Comment: it contains myObject

Comment: Ohh, then you cannot use indexOf on people because people is your array and it contains the objects. So you have to manually find your object based on the ID. Hence, use for loop or forEach loop to find it. And if found then delete that. Here is an example indexOf: var array = [2, 9, 9];
array.indexOf(2);     // will return 0
array.indexOf(7);     // will return -1

Comment: can you please show the implementation in the deletePeople function, so I can see how it works.

Comment: See updated answer. This is what I understood from your question if it is like that then it will work.

Comment: the funny thing is  I apply the code, and the delete button is not taking in place. no action when delete button is pressed and no console errors

Comment: if you maybe show a plunker, to see that your code works or not

Comment: So, here I attached a plunker example. Go through with that.

Comment: Can you do it without ng-repeat?

Answer (score 0):

You must fill `ng-click` action to your function in your controller.
If your button was in `ng-repeat` maybe you must sent parameter in you delete function.